# Calculating Time from Coordinate

Tags: python, javascript, algorithm, coordinates

For my application I am searching for an API or an algorithm for clicking point time and time zone. I dont know how I can do this but after getting time I want to calculate giving coordinate sun rise/set time... I prefer python but javascript is okay.

I know [EarthTools](http://www.earthtools.org/) gives the information you need but I want to use it for local needs. In EarthTools I noticed that the given time is wrong, it is approximately one hour back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used this [sun rise algorithm based on the one for the US Naval Observatory](http://williams.best.vwh.net/sunrise_sunset_algorithm.htm) in the past. It does a good job of explaining the steps. Over the years I have used it in C, C++, VBA, Python...